# Find anywhere epoch times in milliseconds in a log and replace them to human readable time

Tags: linux

I would like to find and replace all epoch times in milliseconds with human readable times. I got already a solution how to do that, if the epoch times is in the first column for example, but not randomly searching for 13 digits and replace it then with time like "23:59:59 01.01.1980"
This is to be done on a Linux machine

So the epoch times could be like:

> sms address="+********" body="This is some example text "
> date="1620053279300" locked="0" protocol="0" read="1" status="-1"
> type="1"/>

or even

> some log some log "1602674980448"

or

> some log some log 1602674980448 some log some log

Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `perl`:

```
perl -MPOSIX -pe 's{(?<!\d)([1-9]\d{9})(\d{3})(?!\d)}{
                  strftime "%FT%T.$2%z",localtime$1}ge' < your-file
```

Here matching on sequences of 13 digits (and no more than that) starting with a non-0 one, so assuming timestamps are in the 2001-09-09T01:46:40.000+0000 - 2286-11-20T17:46:39.999+0000 range using unambiguous and standard `2021-05-03T15:47:59.300+0100` format (you can adapt the `strftime()` format to your taste).

If that still ends up reformatting numbers that are not meant to be timestamps, you can reduce the risk of false positives by  only reformatting numbers that are within a certain range, like from one year ago to now with:

```
perl -MPOSIX -pe '
  BEGIN{$start = ($end = time) - 366*24*60*60}
  s{(?<!\d)([1-9]\d{9})(\d{3})(?!\d)}{
    $start <= $1 && $1 <= $end ?
      strftime "%FT%T.$2%z",localtime$1 :
      $&
   }ge' < your-file
```